# JQuery list of elements

Tags: jquery

i have a HTML page, like this:

```
<div class="class1 class2 class3" >
   <div class="title">
       <a class="class5">Options</a>
   </div>
   <div class="class6">
       <a class="class7" >Clear All</a>
   </div>
   <div class="class8 disabled">
       <ul class="class9">
           <li>
               <label>Size:</label>
               <span class="option">150</span>
           </li>
           <li>
               <label>Color:</label>
               <span class="option">Red</span>
           </li>
       </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

and a JQuery, on document ready, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var optionTexts = [];
    var _selectedOptions = $( ".class1 class2 class3" ).find( "class9" ).find("li");


    _selectedOptions.each(function(i, v){
        optionTexts.push($(this).text())
    });
    console.log('options: ' + optionTexts);
});
```

What i need is to retrive an array of **li** where i can iterate and, for each **li**, i can extract the intnerText of elements like:

**Element**: Size

**Value**: 150

**Element**: Color

**Value**: Red

Comment: Do you want this to be an Array of Objects or text?

Comment: An array of two fields, Elements and Value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not far off.  To select an element with multiple classes, combine them without spaces, eg:

```
.class1.class2.class3
```

and to select a child (not necessarily direct-child) use a space - this is the same as `.find`

```
$(".class1 .class9") == $(".class1").find(".class9")
```

You can then use `.map` to extract the values you want from each `li` giving you your object with two fields Element/Value.

Finally, use `.toArray` to convert the `.map` output to an array, giving the one-liner (formatted for clarity):

```js
var result = $(".class1.class2.class3 .class9 li")
  .map(function() {
    return {
      "Element": $("label", this).text(),
      "Value": $(".option", this).text()
    }
  })
  .toArray();
  
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class1 class2 class3">
  <div class="title">
    <a class="class5">Options</a>
  </div>
  <div class="class6">
    <a class="class7">Clear All</a>
  </div>
  <div class="class8 disabled">
    <ul class="class9">
      <li>
        <label>Size:</label>
        <span class="option">150</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>Color:</label>
        <span class="option">Red</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for editing my post. Also, your solution is much cleaner, I like it :)

Comment: @Mahatmasamatman thanks your's is fine (I gave it a +1) and keeps OPs original array with push which can help people make steps rather than leaps.  .map is very useful, but can take a while to get used to.

Answer (score 1):

First you select `.class1.class2.class3`, that's one element so you can select it with these 3 classes (might I suggest using an `ID` or a more readable class?), and then `.class9` inside it. Then you iterate through every `<li>`, find its `<span>` and `<label>` and capture the text.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var optionTexts = [];
  $(".class1.class2.class3 .class9").find("li").each(function() {
    optionTexts.push({
      'element': $(this).find("label").text(),
      'value': $(this).find("span").text()
    });
  });
  console.log('options: ', optionTexts);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class1 class2 class3">
  <div class="title">
    <a class="class5">Options</a>
  </div>
  <div class="class6">
    <a class="class7">Clear All</a>
  </div>
  <div class="class8 disabled">
    <ul class="class9">
      <li>
        <label>Size:</label>
        <span class="option">150</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>Color:</label>
        <span class="option">Red</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```